# How to translate language strings - zenity command-line utility

Tags: user-interface, localization, locale, language-translation, zenity

I am using zenity utility in my shell scripts on ubuntu for displaying GUI dialogs. I wanted to know how to achieve language translations when system locale is changed.

```
zenity --question --title="" --text="Hello World. How was the day today..Good?" --width="500" --height="20"
```

In the above command, how to achieve language translations for the text in English "Hello World. How was the day today..Good?" in different languages. If I change my system locale from English to other language, the "Yes", "No" buttons text that comes by default with zenity changes automatically, but how to translate my custom text?

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the answer to this too. I found this question while looking for the answer. I was on the right track searching for how to use .po and .pot files in bash scripts.

It looks like the [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) program and friends can be used to do this.

I found this good [blog post](http://eyesfreelinux.ninja/posts/internationalising-shell-scripts-with-gettext.html) that explains it well. Although he is using this for `echo` this can also be used for the strings for Zenity.

The basics are this. To work with `gettext` you need to set two environment variables at the top of the script. Lines like these:

`export TEXTDOMAIN=$(basename $0)  # Name of this script
export TEXTDOMAINDIR==$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")/locale # Location of this script`

This will allow you to put your translations in folders next to your script the default location for TEXTDOMAINDIR if you do not set it is `/usr/share/locale`.

and source the [gettext.sh](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Preparing-Shell-Scripts.html) script in your script with

`source gettext.sh`

After that you can change your Zenity text strings that need translated by wrapping them with `eval_gettext` in a subcommand.

For example:

`zenity --info --title="Now opening programs!" --text="I will now open the starup programs for you. This will help you get the computer setup quicker. I will let you know when I am finished" --timeout=5`

Becomes:

`zenity --info --title="$(eval_gettext "Now opening programs!")" --text="$(eval_gettext "I will now open the starup programs for you. This will help you get the computer setup quicker. I will let you know when I am finished")" --timeout=5`

So the syntax for use with Zenity text options, like `--title` and `--text`, looks like this:

`"$(eval_gettext "Text string")"`

We have the `"Text string"` in double quotes.

This is inside a `eval_gettext` subcommand: `$(eval_gettext "Text string")` which is wrapped in double quotes so that Zenity gets the string returned from the subcommand in double quotes.
`"$(eval_gettext "Text string")"`

Next you need to create a translation template file (.pot) using [xgettext](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html).

`xgettext -L Shell -o myscript.pot myscript`

The .pot file that is generated can be given to your translator(s) who can use programs like [Poedit](https://poedit.net/) to create .po files for their language. The translator(s) can then send you the .po file to be included in your project.

If you use Poedit will also create the .mo file for you when you save it. In the `TEXTDOMAINDIR` above then you can create in the same folder where your script is the following folder structure:

`locale/<LANG>/LC_MESSAGES/`

Replace  with the language code of the translation. I placed the .po file to translate in the `LC_MESSAGES` folder, then saved it with Poedit to create the .mo file. The .po should be named the same as the`TEXTDOMAIN` variable above plus .mo. If your script ends in .sh include this to. ie. For `myscript.sh` the .mo file would be `myscript.sh.mo`.

If you do not use Poedit you can also use `msgfmt` to make the .mo file:

`msgfmt -v  myscript.sh.po -o myscript.sh.mo`

To test your script with a language you can run it like so. ie. For the German language code **de**
`LANGUAGE=de ./myscript.sh`

File structure for myscript.sh, German (de), .po, .mo and folders:

- myscript.sh
- locale

  - de
  - LC_MESSAGES

    - myscript.sh.mo
    - myscript.sh.po